# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Contents must be presorted

Tags: java, xml, exception, sax, hashtree

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Contents must be presorted - added value -2146647068 is less than preceding value 2147447602
    at org.netbeans.core.output2.IntList.add(IntList.java:76)
    at org.netbeans.core.output2.AbstractLines.lineUpdated(AbstractLines.java:764)
    at org.netbeans.core.output2.OutWriter.write(OutWriter.java:216)
    at org.netbeans.core.output2.OutWriter.doWrite(OutWriter.java:453)
    at org.netbeans.core.output2.OutWriter.println(OutWriter.java:488)
    at org.netbeans.core.output2.OutWriter.print(OutWriter.java:526)
    at org.netbeans.core.output2.NbIO$IOColorLinesImpl.println(NbIO.java:494)
    at org.openide.windows.IOColorLines.println(IOColorLines.java:88)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.StandardLogger.formatColoredMessageWithTime(StandardLogger.java:353)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.StandardLogger.buildFinished(StandardLogger.java:318)
[catch] at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.NbBuildLogger.buildFinished(NbBuildLogger.java:440)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.fireBuildFinished(Project.java:2093)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:290)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:541)
    at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)
```

I received this Exception when running an SAX Parser that needs to read large chunks of XML data. The data is stored into a Hashtree. After about 15 mins of running, this exception was found. What does it mean?

Comment: Please post  the code that threw this exception.

Comment: Um, the code is 900 lines long.

Comment: I am guessing, but chances are that you are overflowing here. Java has no unsigned types, so probably you get a negative number by adding "too much".

Comment: @user2741620: Start minimizing your code. That's the whole point of trying to post a minimal test case to reproduce it: very often it will answer the question for you, without you having to expose it to the whole world.

Answer (score 2):

It means: somewhere in the program there is an int that reached its maximum value. Integers have a maximum value of 2,147,483,647. When they reach this value, they loop back to their minimum value, -2,147,483,648. What probably happened is that there is a loop in the program that constantly increments an integer. When the program runs for long enough, the integer reaches its maximum value and loops back to its minimum value. The program doesn't expect this, so it throws an error.

Comment: Is it possible to know which is the Int that caused this?

Comment: @user2741620 Yes, it's the one at org.netbeans.core.output2.IntList.add(IntList.java:76). Without the code, I can't tell you more.