# How to save a large number of elements in a LinkedHashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap, integer, overflow

I have a large number of elements that I want to save in a `LinkedHashMap`. The problem is that I have really a large number of elements, i.e. more than the size of the `Integer` class. Since the `size()` method of the `LinkedHashMap` class returns an `int`, I think that the number of elements in the `LinkedHashMap` can not exceed the possibility of the `int`. Is that right? If yes, what can I do?

I should also mention that I actually don't know where exactly the problem is occurring in my code. That is just my guess that the problem is with the `size()` method of the `LinkedHashMap`. I just get the same error as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19345337/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-contents-must-be-presorted).

Comment: "If yes, what can I do?". Rethink your design. Why are trying to store a Map with more than 2 billion values in the first place?

Comment: Don't forget that each entry in a `LinkedHashMap` takes 40 bytes plus the memory overhead of the actual elements, so that's a minimum of 80 gigabytes of _heap_.  You probably don't want a `LinkedHashMap`.  You might want a database.  You might want something else entirely.

Comment: You really need to preserve the iteration order of such an amount of data?

Comment: Dear @Tunaki and other friends,

Thank you very much for your comments. After your comments, I really realized what a catastrophe I was gonna make! So, I changed my program in a way that it works correctly.
Actually, I wanted to extract some information for each word of a novel and the number of words in the novel was absolutely large. So, I changed the code in a way that I could process the text chapter by chapter and the problem was solved.
Thanks again for your helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe it's a good idea to have a Map with such a large number of values but if you really want to go ahead with it, you can override `LinkedHashMap` and use the `BigInteger` class to increase the size.

```
public class MyLinkedHashMap<K,V> extends LinkedHashMap<K,V> {
    BigInteger mySize;

    @Override
    public V put(K key, V Value) {
        if (super.put(key,value) == null) // this will still eventually throw an exception because of the 'size' variable incrementing internally in the HashMap
            mySize.add(BigInteger.ONE);
    }

    @Override
    public V remove(Object key) {
        if (super.remove(key) != null)
            mySize.subtract(BigInteger.ONE);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }        

    public BigInteger getSize() {
        return mySize;
    }
}
```

Note that because you cannot change the return type of the `size()` method you must create your own size method and variable to retrieve the size of the map.

Additionally, you may actually need to override `HashMap` itself because its `put()` method will still increment the existing `size` variable `int` value and will eventually cause it to go beyond the range of a Java Integer.

Lastly, just to be clear, this is **NOT** a good idea at all because there are many pitfalls in trying to repurpose an existing data structure in this manner (e.g. forgetting to override other methods that modify/use the `size` variable, programmer errors which can harm the validity of the original data structure, or other instance variables/side effects that were never originally intended to handle such large sizes etc.).